# Select apenas 24 registros por dia

Tags: mysql

Preciso de ajuda pra elaborar uma query que selecione apenas 24 registros de cada dia.

Por exemplo:

Dia 1: 100 registros
Dia 2: 50 registros
Dia 3: 34 registros

Quero pegar apenas 24 de cada dia: 1, 2 e 3...(nesse exemplo somaria: 72 registros)

```
SELECT date_format(hora,'%d/%m/%Y'), SUM(ponto) FROM `pontos` WHERE user = "teste" AND hora >= '2019-08-20' AND hora < NOW()
```

*Da forma que está, minha query traz a soma de todos os registros

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Charles, você quer pegar apenas 1 valor por hora, é isso? tipo, pegar o valor da hora 00:00 do dia, depois o valor da hora 01:00 do dia e assim até dar as 24 horas e somar, é isto?

Comment: Como vc sabe que o valor 170 não é o resultado dos 24 registros? O que tem na coluna "ponto"?

Comment: tem o valor 1 (UM), onde quero pegar 24 pontos de cada dia

Comment: em um dia o cara pode fazer quantos pontos ele quiser (mais de MIL), mas eu quero pegar somente 24 por dia

Comment: @Heathcliff sim, isso é uma solução que resolve também, pois pegando 1 ponto por hora eu terei os 24 de cada dia.

Comment: @Sam acredito que o comando NOW considera a hora do registro, onde os registros de hoje(conforme o print) entraram em um horário inferior ao horário de NOW

Comment: Postei uma resposta atualizada agora. Veja se resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use uma subquery com `LIMIT 24`. Crie um alias para `date_format(hora,'%d/%m/%Y')` e use `GROUP BY` nesse alias para retornar todas as datas com o resultado de `SUM(ponto)`:

```
SELECT date_format(hora,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dia, SUM(ponto) FROM
(SELECT hora, ponto
      FROM `pontos`
      WHERE user = "teste" AND hora >= '2019-08-20' AND hora < NOW()
      LIMIT 24
) AS subquery
GROUP BY dia
```

**[Veja no SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5338ea/1)**

Comment: muito obrigado! Acredito que esse é o caminho certo...no entanto a query trouxe somente os 24 pontos do dia 2, eu gostaria que trouxesse a soma dos dias anteriores a partir da data 2019-08-20, nessa imagem da pra ver os registros das datas anteriores: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/table-png-e590c062-3755-4bc8-93aa-3545aa8a8858

Comment: Eu atualizei o código na resposta. Testa aí de novo.

Comment: Aqui ainda não funcionou, https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/002/313/781/full/query.png?1567441302, mas eu vi o seu teste no SQLFIDDLE e é exatamente isso que eu preciso, eu vou tentar descobrir aqui porque não trouxe o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Tenta ver qual a versão do seu MySQL.

Comment: Opa, removi o LIMIT 24 e agora ele trouxe os resultados da soma do dia: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/query-png-0c3a1667-0935-4f7a-b364-fd49228888b8, com isso eu vou fazer uma if no php onde se o valor for maior que 24, ele considera apenas 24 e soma tudo.

Comment: Bem estranho isso, o limit deveria funcionar :(... Mas se a resposta foi favorável, creio que mereça finalizar a pergunta com ✔.. Abs!

Comment: Agradeço muito pela ajuda! Abs!

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o [`LIMIT`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx):

```
SELECT date_format(hora,'%d/%m/%Y'), SUM(ponto)
FROM pontos
WHERE user = "teste"
  AND hora >= '2019-08-20'
  AND hora < NOW()
LIMIT 24
```

Comment: não funcionou...pois mesmo com o LIMIT 24, a query continua trazendo a soma do total de registros do dia. *Anexei uma imagem na pergunta.